# JAVA new Thread run() referencing class it was started from

Tags: java, java-threads

I have some code like this:

```
package somepackage.somefolder;
public class MyClass {
    public MyClass () {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                SomeOtherClass something = new SomeOtherClass(REFERENCE-TO-MyClass-NEEDED!!!);
            }
        }
    }

    public someFunction(){
        //do stuff...
    }
}

package somepackage.someOtherfolder;
public class SomeOtherClass {
    public SomeOtherClass (MyClass mc) {
        mc.someFunction();
    }
}
```

How to send reference of the actual instance of MyClass to the other class so it could access MyClass someFunction()?

If I call it directly like:

```
SomeOtherClass something = new SomeOtherClass (this);
```

It points to Thread itself where I need it to point to the parent class it was started from, that is MyClass.

I cannot reference it as `MyClass mc = new MyClass` inside SomeOtherClass as it would create new instance of the class.

Comment: `new SomeOtherClass(MyClass.this);`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes, thank you very much - that is the correct answer (I was so close)...but I do not know how to flag your answer as the right one?

Comment: You don't. The question is a duplicate of many previous similar questions, and I have closed it as a duplicate (please see the link to the question and answer at the top of your question). I also added a comment to summarize the salient point in the answer to give you a quick and dirty answer as well.